# Type or namespace TM_TYPE does not exists in Emgu.CV.CvEnum in EmguCV 3.0

Tags: c#, emgucv

I'm getting error in EmguCV is there anyone knows the problem here is my code:

```
        Image<Bgr, byte> source = new Image<Bgr, byte>(@"D:\work\htdocs\coc\public\Barracks\b6.bmp"); // Image B
        Image<Bgr, byte> template = new Image<Bgr, byte>(@"D:\work\htdocs\coc\public\Barracks\Cropped\b6-1.bmp"); // Image A
        Image<Bgr, byte> imageToShow = source.Copy();

        using (Image<Gray, float> result = source.MatchTemplate(template, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.TM_TYPE.CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED))
        {
            double[] minValues, maxValues;
            Point[] minLocations, maxLocations;
            result.MinMax(out minValues, out maxValues, out minLocations, out maxLocations);

            // You can try different values of the threshold. I guess somewhere between 0.75 and 0.95 would be good.
            if (maxValues[0] > 0.9)
            {
                // This is a match. Do something with it, for example draw a rectangle around it.
                Rectangle match = new Rectangle(maxLocations[0], template.Size);
                imageToShow.Draw(match, new Bgr(Color.Red), 3);
            }
        }

        // Show imageToShow in an ImageBox (here assumed to be called imageBox1)
        imageBox1.Image = imageToShow;
```

The problem I'm getting is:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'TM_TYPE' does not exist in the namespace 'Emgu.CV.CvEnum' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this:

```css
using (Image<Gray, float> result = source.MatchTemplate(template, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.TemplateMatchingType.CcoeffNormed))
```

Comment: Thank you, It works. Can why ? Is it changed in 3.0 ?

Comment: yes , it is changed in 3.0 -- your wellcome @Sarp Aykent